# Dynamically weaving several arrays together in octave and matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

Dynamically weaving several arrays together

I know I can weave two signals together using the reshape command

Example:

```
array1=[1,2,3,4]
array2=[10,20,30,40]
weave_sig=reshape([array1(:)';array2(:)'],1,[])'
```

would give me

```
weave_sig=[1;10;2;20;3;30;4;40]
```

How can I weave multiple generated signals using values in **array1** and calculated using **sig1** Please note the array1 will have several dozen items and I'm trying to figure out a way not to break array1 into separate arrays.  Basically I'm trying to weave the signals variable **sig1** creates together

```
array1=[35.2,.3;101,.5;90.5,.7]; %[freq,amp] %will have dozens of values in array1

Fs = 8000;% Sampling frequency
t=linspace(0,2*pi,Fs);
sig1=zeros(1,length(t));
for ww=1:1:size(array1,1) %num of rows
  sig1 = array1(ww,2)*sin(array1(ww,1)*t);
  %weave_sig=reshape([array1(:)';array2(:)'],1,[])'; %part I'm not sure about

end
```

Ps: I'm using octave 4.0 which is like matlab

Comment: `reshape([array1(:)';array2(:)'],1,[])` is the same as `[array1(:), array2(:)]`

Comment: If your arrays are all separate variables, you don't have a choice but to type them all out then use `reshape`.  That's why using many variables in your code is very bad. It makes code unmaintainable.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: It's actually the same as `array3 = [array1(:), array2(:)].';` `array3 = array3(:).'` (unless Octave works differently).

Comment: @rayryeng all the items are in array1 I'm trying to avoid splitting them out

Comment: @RickT I don't understand.  If all items are in `array1`, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? I thought you had several arrays and you wanted to interleave all elements together.

Comment: @rayryeng I'm trying to inter-weave all the signals calculated by sig1 (which the values are taken from array1) I updated the code and text to see if that makes it a little clearer